# Showing the no. of entries in the template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

i created a form form simple entries of question , i wanted to show the total no. of questions entered in the template.
Can anyone show me how to do it ?

Comment: what determines the number of questions ? Is it a queryset object ?

Comment: i created a loop for display like this  : - 
{{for i in question_list }}
{{ endfor }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax :-

```
<p>{{ question_list|length}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to calculate this in your view and send the number to your template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import Entry


def form_view(request):
    total_entries = Entry.objects.count()
    # your other code
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'total': total_entries})
```

In your template:

```
The total is {{ total }}
```

Comment: but is it not too long , rather i would like to use just a simple code like in the other answer .

Comment: That's fine - but there is a reason its recommended to do it in the view :)